# Why is my AWS Lambda being flagged as being too large when deploying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy a Lambda using CDK/CloudFormation.  I am seeing the following error in the CloudFormation logs as part of the deployment and is causing a rollback:

```
Unzipped size must be smaller than 36419736 bytes (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 5bf11ebc-3822-4ff5-ac24-15051357916b)
```

Why am I seeing this error? The [docs on Lambda quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) state that the maximum zipped size is 50MB and total unzipped size needs to be <250MB, both of which I am abiding by.

Comment: Are you also bundling additional libraries? Are you using Lambda Layers? The quota applies to libraries that you include as well as Lambda Layers.

Comment: FIrst upload on S3 then usingS3 upload in lambda you will get extra space else use Lambda Layers

Comment: I have one lambda and 4 layers, where each is considerably lower than 50MB and the sum is less than 250MB.

Comment: How many Lambdas total do you have for the account? Is it possible that you're bumping against the account-level limit of 75 GB (including all Lambda and layer versions).?

Comment: It would also be helpful to show some more context. Is this appearing as part of the deploy, or somewhere else in the process?

Comment: Yes, this in in the deploy process and the error appears in the CloudFormation logs which is triggering a rollback.

Comment: How do you deploy it? Can you check exactly what files you deploy? Can you query your AWS Lambda deployment for the available quota right before? Can you try and zip the files and upload it to the Lambda console? Are you adding to an already existing stack? You might have success if you try and create a completely new Lambda and a new stack, possibly connecting to what you already have if needed.

Comment: Do you know how to check the account level limit to see if you're over the 75 GB limit, @Parsifal? I'm getting the same error that @john is getting. And it's every Lambda in my account that I've been deploying with CodePipeline for over two years. Now, suddenly, they're all failing.

Comment: @Gillfish - I would start with `aws lambda list-functions --query 'Functions[][FunctionName,Version,CodeSize]' --output table`. You'll have to run this in all regions, and add up the results, as well as run the similar operation for layers across all regions.

Comment: I just found out that the usage of your 75 GB account-level code storage limit is shown in the [Lambda dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/discover).